# this code is showing error :-- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: tkinter, attributeerror, tkinter-entry

''' 
   'this is showing error'
   'please help me to resolve this problem'

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()


def loginc():
    print(e1.get()) #getting value of entry


l=Label(root)
f=Frame(l,pady="25",padx="25")
lb1=Label(f,text="Enter ID: ",font="lucida 10 bold").grid(column=0,row=2,pady="4")

e1=Entry(f,width="28").grid(column=1,row=2)

lb2=Label(f,text="Enter Password: ",font="lucida 10 bold").grid(column=0,row=3,pady="4")
e2=Entry(f,width="28").grid(column=1,row=3)

btn=Button(f,text="login",bg="green",fg="white",width="10",font="lucida 10 bold",command=loginc)
btn.grid(columnspan=3,row=5,pady="10")
f.grid(column=0,row=6)
l.grid(column=0,row=7)

root.mainloop()
```

how can i solve this problem 
'''

Comment: I'm guessing the line throwing the error is `print(e1.get())`? It means object `e1` is NoneType. You may need to pass e1 into the `loginc()` function as a parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)